# Python fmin - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple' ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, optimization, typeerror, args, multiparameter

I am trying to minimize my likelihood function with the `par` parameter only, the rest: `n,T,r,log_x, gft_y` are supposed to be fixed in the optimization. When I put them in the `args` to fix them I get back the following errors:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\phelg\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16344/2785678381.py", line 4, in <module>
    result = fmin(mrg_lik,initial_guess, args)

  File "C:\Users\phelg\anaconda3\envs\Financial_Econometrics\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 580, in fmin
    res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)

  File "C:\Users\phelg\anaconda3\envs\Financial_Econometrics\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 750, in _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[k] = func(sim[k])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The likelihood function:

```
def likelihood(par,n,T,r,log_x,gft_y):
    # takes inputs par, n, T, r,log_x and gft_y
    # returns F,log_h,gft_q,u,v,z and Gamma
    A=np.zeros(shape=(T,n,n))
    B=np.zeros(shape=(T,n,n))
    try:
        for t in range(0,T):
            A[t]= mapping(gft_q[t], 10e-8)[0]
        for t in range(0,T):
            B[t]= np.diag(np.sqrt(np.exp(log_h[t])))
        for t in range(0,T):
            lik = -0.5*(n*np.log(2*pi) + np.log(np.linalg.det(A[t]@B[t]@A[t])) +(z[t] /A[t] @z[t].T))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: input is of wrong format")    
    F = -(np.sum(lik))
    return F,log_h,gft_q,u,v,z,Gamma
    print(F,log_h,gft_q,u,v,z,Gamma)
    
par= np.ones(shape=(26,))
result = likelihood(par,n,T,r,log_x,gft_y)
```

The optimization:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin
initial_guess = np.full((126,), 0.1)
args = (n,T,r,log_x,gft_y) #fixed arguments in likelihood function during optimization
result = fmin(likelihood,initial_guess,args) #should give back the par which minimize the likelihood
fitted_params = result.x
```

**Update:** The likelihood function returned more than one result and the fmin function was trying to minimize them all. Correction:

```
return F
```

instead

```
return F,log_h,gft_q,u,v,z,Gamma
```

Now I finally got the fmin function running without errors. Note that my code is wrong in a way that the results for the optimization are incorrect (it gives me an array with the initial_guess in it). But that is another issue to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Your function call to `fmin` seems off.  [The docs say](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin) it should be `fmin(function, guess, <tuple of other args>)`.  So I would have expected you to use this: `fmin(likelihood, initial_guess, args)`

#### Note on how to understand the errors

In your first attempt you got `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`, that indicates `fmin` was expecting a function (`callable`) but it received a tuple.  Which was because you were calling `likelihood` with arguments: `likelihood(...)`, instead of passing it as is.

In the second case you get the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.  That tells you `fmin` was expecting an array, but it received a generic sequence.  On looking at the arguments, you will notice you defined your `initial_guess` as `[0.4*np.ones((1, 26))]` which is a single item list with a 1x26 array as the value.

For the third case, `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` means there's a `array[i] = <value>` somewhere, where instead of giving a `<value>` that matches the array type, it is a sequence.  This is further clarified above in the stack trace in: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'`.  From this you can tell, the value is a `tuple` instead of `float`.  The issue could be in `likelihood`.  Are you sure the shape should be `1x26` instead of just a simple 1D array of length 26, so `shape = (26,)`?

**Edit:** see the `scipy` source code for [_minimize_neldermead](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py#L635), lines 792-793, and 746.  As I read that, a 1D array is expected.  Even though it might seem otherwise, `1x26` is actually 2D.  just look at `initial_guess.ndim`.

Comment: I think Initial guess is expected to be an `ndarray`, but you are providing a list of array.  Trying using `initial_guess = np.full((1, 26), 0.4)`

Comment: That seems to be fixed the initial_guess, but I still get ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Could be the `args` is not the correct format?

Comment: Could you include the full stack trace in the question?

Comment: I edited my answer and added some comments.  It's very difficult to pin point the issue without getting more context, but I have the feeling it's the shape of the initial guess array, and what `likelihood` expects.  Is there a good reason to use `1x26` instead of just a 1D array of length 26?

Comment: @HelgaPataki I added more explanation with a link to the `scipy` source

Comment: Thank you! I update the initial_guess to be 1D and also the rest of the parameters where the initial_guess will be stacked, all of them 1D. The idea is that we give an initial guess to par and that we stack into the par0, par1...

Comment: I added the full code for context which shows all inputs for `likelihood`  especially how `r`,  `log_x` and `gft_y` are presented, in (4,2) , (4,2) and (4,1) arrays. See under **Calculating measures from the dataframe**